# swift how to pick documents from device local with controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I was searching for class or tutorial for how to present to the user a controller like `UIImagePickerViewController` for local documents in the device like pdf,text,Doc and so on but no luck .

can some one point me to the right direction .

i know about `UIDocumentPickerViewController` that gives you to import from iCloud , thats not what i am looking for  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know, mr jobs didn't like this idea, [read here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/06/steve-jobs-on-the-file-system/), 
so as far as I know there is no direct way to browse files like on android, I hope this helps.

Comment: well i dont know whay but its not directly browsing like in android more like show the document you have like images well preaty sucks tho

Comment: i'm afraid it is not even possible to browse for doc/pdf/text files on iOS.

Comment: browsing is something, and sharing is something else.